# Facebook comments lost after enabling https

Tags: facebook, comments

I just enabled https on blogger on a custom domain and fixed already mixed content. One of the problems I am encountering is the facebook comments. All are lost. I already put a code to instruct facebook plugins to use the old http. Here is the code:

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.url.canonical.http' property='og:url'/>
```

I scraped already in FB Debugger tool and it seems fine. But still the comments in the blog are not appearing. ANyone can help me on this?

Here is the sample page:  https://www.ladyandhersweetescapes.com/2014/04/old-dubai-do-it-yourself-walking-tour.html

And here is the fb debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ladyandhersweetescapes.com%2F2014%2F04%2Fold-dubai-do-it-yourself-walking-tour.html

Thank you so much!